# How to make my discord bot detects two or more specific words and responds

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I’m trying to make my discord bot respond when it detected two or more specific words in other's msg. Something like when someone has sent a message with “Bot” and “jokes” like “Hey Bot, tell me some jokes!”, the bot will respond to it. These are my code: (Cause I'm a Hongkonger and this bot are also designed for the Hongkongers so there are some Chinese in my code, but I'll write down the meaning behind the # then U guys can understand it.)

```
import discord
import time
import random

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    name = message.author.display_name
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith("喂Rikky!"): #"喂" is mean "Hey!". So this part mean "Hey Rikky!"
        await message.channel.send('係到!咩事呢?') #This Part is too hard to explain cause this is Cantonese. It is the same meaning as "I'm here, what's up?"

    if "Rikky, 講個笑話嚟聽下" in message.content: #This part mean "Rikky, tell me a joke!"
        await message.channel.send("我唔識講笑話架，你當我係Siri咩?") #This part mean "I'm not good at telling jokes"

client.run('***')
```

This is part of my code. I've tried

```
    if "Bot" + "joke" in message.content:
        await message.channel.send("我唔識講笑話架，你當我係Siri咩?")
```

but it doesn't work.

If it is possible, please tell me how. Thanks for spending so much time reading this question! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

> if "bot" and "joke" in message.content.lower():
> await message.channel.send("我唔識講笑話架，你當我係Siri咩?")

or

> ```
> if "bot" in message.content.lower() and "joke" in message.content.lower():
> ```

```
    await message.channel.send("我唔識講笑話架，你當我係Siri咩?")
```

Comment: Thanks, at first it doesn't work. But after I changed it into                                                               
if "Rikky" in message.content and "joke" in message.content:
        await message.channel.send("我唔識講笑話架，你當我係Siri咩?") it works!

Comment: Better to lowercase the message.content and rikky in the If statement, so it works for both lowercase and uppercase Rikky in the content.

Comment: Thanks Sardar Arslan!